# How to pick the right resistor and capacitors on KiCad?

Tags: pcb-design, kicad

I am making a PCB for the first time and I am having trouble picking the correct footprint for my resistors and capacitors. This is one of the resistors that I am using ([311-100KHRCT-ND](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/yageo/RC0603FR-07100KL/726889)). That item is on DigiKey and it's a 0603 size resistor (1.6mm X 0.8 mm).

The capacitors that I am using are ([1276-1076-1-ND](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/samsung-electro-mechanics/CL05A105KP5NNNC/3886734?s=N4IgTCBcDaIIxgOwDYC0cAML2oHIBEQBdAXyA)). They can also be found on DigiKey and their size is 0402.

The problem that I am having with the resistor is the sizes on KiCad. A 0603 on KiCad is (0.64mm X 0.4mm). Does this mean that I have to choose a bigger footprint on KiCad? If so, which one? I didn't see anything that would fit my resistor.

An issue that I am having with the capacitor is picking the correct capacitor type. Do I use `Capacitor SMD`, `Capacitor Tantalum_SMD`, or `Capacitor THT`?

Comment: Please tell us the footprint names you are using for these.  In my experience, the "basic" footprints work well enough without having to download and install manufacturer-specific footprints for every different e.g. 0603 resistor in the circuit.  The capacitor type you want is "Capacitor SMD".

Answer (score 4):

There are two different package size systems. You'll notice the resistor you linked to is listed as 0603 (1608 metric). So, there is the 0603 package, and then there is the equivalent 1608 **metric** package. In my own personal experience (I'm in the US), most people would refer to that as an 0603 resistor.

The Kicad footprint seems to be for a 0603 **metric** package. Indeed when you search up "0603 metric size" you will see that it is 0.6x0.3mm.

So, perhaps Kicad has a standard 1608 metric package footprint that will work for you. If not, it is really very easy to make your own using your desired resistor's datasheet or to import one off of the web - try UltraLibrary for that, it has all the ECAD models for the 311-100KHRCT-ND.

Comment: _" In my own personal experience (I'm in the US), most people would refer to that as an 0603 resistor."_ From my experience the Imperial code is used by default even in Europe.